# Programatically changing the ContentInset of a UIScrollView doesn't actually change anything

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` created in Interface builder, now in that `UIScrollView` there's a `UITextField`. When the keyboard opens, I'd like to change the `ContentInset` of the `UIScrollView` to fit the keyboard.

I've done this previously through a package called `RXKeyboard`, which reactively gives me the height of the keyboard:

```
RxKeyboard.instance.visibleHeight
    .drive(onNext: { height in
        self.scrollView.contentInset.bottom = height
        print("offset", self.scrollView.contentInset)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Now the `ContentInset` of the `UIScrollView` does change (shown through the print), however, nothing actually changes, and the bottom part of my `UIScrollView`is hidden by the keyboard...

Am I missing something here? I tried moving this into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I tried `layoutSubviews()` after setting the inset, but I can't get this to work.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's right you've set your scrollView's insets to be keyboard's height but as the keyboard comes up you want to make your scrollView Content to come up to keyboard's height.

You have to scroll your scrollView to keyboard height by adjusting it's **contentOffset** property.

```
RxKeyboard.instance.willShowVisibleHeight
        .drive(onNext: { keyboardVisibleHeight in
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.y += keyboardVisibleHeight
        })
        .disposed(by: disposebag)
```

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset) says,

> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.

By setting **contentOffset.y** to keyboard's height, you are telling scrollView to move/scroll to that height.